# GitVersion: always Patch incrementing, Minor is not getting incremented

Tags: semantic-versioning, gitversion

- I have a requirement for Automatic versioning based on branches.
- I have set a tag on my master branch as 1.0.0
- if changes from feature branch get merged to Master then Minor should get incremented as 1.1.0
- if changes from release branch get merged to Master then Patch should be incremented as 1.1.1

but everytime when I merge the code from feature or release branch to master, the patch only get incremented, Minor is not getting incremented. Can anyone help with the branch configuration for my requirement

I have the configuration as below in GitVersion.yml file.

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-informational-format: '{InformationalVersion}'
mode: Mainline
increment: Inherit
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
tag-prefix: '\[vV\]'
major-version-bump-message: '+semver:\\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '+semver:\\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '+semver:\\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '+semver:\\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
tag-pre-release-weight: 60000
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
feature:
regex: ^features?\[/-\]
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag: useBranchName
increment: Minor
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
track-merge-target: false
source-branches: \[\]
tracks-release-branches: true
is-release-branch: false
is-mainline: false
pre-release-weight: 0
release:
regex: ^releases?\[/-\]
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag: beta
increment: Patch
prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
track-merge-target: false
source-branches: \[\]
tracks-release-branches: true
is-release-branch: false
is-mainline: false
pre-release-weight: 0
ignore:
sha: \[\]
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```